# MS Access Advanced Text Seach on single field in target table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I am trying to search a field called "Model" in a table called "ItemSpecs" but I cannot for the life of me figure it out and I have yet to be able to find any examples on google. In addition to searching the field I am trying to add different search methods (e.g. "Contains","Doesn't contain","Begins with", and "Ends with").

What I have so far

So far I the following but all it does is test which drop down item is selected (which works!).

What I still need

From what I have read I will need to query the table and put it into a vbRecordSet and then search that to get what I want? Which i think the skeleton code below will enable me to do that once I can figure out how to get the query results into the record set and then figure out how to query it.

Notes:

Thanks for the help! Imma keep working this damn thing but if someone can figure it out before me it would be great.

```
Private Sub Button_Search_Click()
    If Len(Me.Search_Text.Value & vbNullString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Value"
    Else
        If Me.Search_Preferance.Value = "Starts with" Then
            MsgBox "Starts with"
        ElseIf Me.Search_Preferance.Value = "Ends with" Then
            MsgBox "Ends with"
        ElseIf Me.Search_Preferance.Value = "Contains" Then
            MsgBox "Contains"
        ElseIf Me.Search_Preferance.Value = "Doesn't contain" Then
            MsgBox "Doesn't contain"
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid Seach Preference Selected."
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: If your goal is to display those records which have some field which matches your search criteria, use a `SELECT` query (instead of loading the table into a recordset and then searching the recordset).

Comment: It almost seems like you are referring to the [Wildcard](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html)?

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that you are doing this on a form where the RecordSource is set to "ItemSpecs" (or a select query based off of that table where one of the included columns is "Model"):

```vb
Private Sub Button_Search_Click()
    If Len(Me.Search_Text.Value & vbNullString) = 0 Then
        Me.FilterOn = False
        Me.Filter = vbNullString
    Else
        Dim Txt As String
        Txt = Me.Search_Text.Value
        Select Case Me.Search_Preferance.Value 
        Case "Starts with": Me.Filter = "Model Like """ & Txt & "*"""
        Case "Ends with": Me.Filter = "Model Like ""*" & Txt & """"
        Case "Contains": Me.Filter = "Model Like ""*" & Txt & "*"""
        Case "Doesn't contain": Me.Filter = "Model Not Like ""*" & Txt & "*"""
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Invalid Seach Preference Selected."
        End Select
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: actually all I have at the moment is an empty list box called "Search_Results". But this has been a trmendous help :) If I figure it out i'll make your answer as the answer :)